# How to initially hide lazy loaded images in swiper

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading, swiper.js

I am trying to get [lazy loading in Swiper plugin](https://swiperjs.com/api/#lazy) enabled with the following intentions:

1. Make 2 instances of images i.e. one for thumbnail and other for original image
2. Original will lazy load and thumbnail will be loaded normally.
3. Show original image only when it has been loaded completely. Until then thumbnail will be displayed.
4. Apply hover effect to toggle between thumbnail and original image (original image may and may not exist. so hover effect should be enabled after checking if original image exist or not.)

Here is what I have done so far. [codepen](https://codepen.io/assadnazar/pen/XWKEWzp)

```
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img class="thumb" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/zingfitassets/onerebelredesign/instructor/BD8I8492_20181213103730.jpg">
      <img data-srcset="https://s3.amazonaws.com/zingfitassets/onerebelredesign/contentobject/Mark_Portrait_V2_20181213103730.gif" class="swiper-lazy orig-img" style="display: none;">
      <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img class="thumb" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/zingfitassets/onerebelredesign/instructor/BD8I8492_20181213103730.jpg">
      <img data-srcset="https://s3.amazonaws.com/zingfitassets/onerebelredesign/contentobject/Mark_Portrait_V2_20181213103730.gif" class="swiper-lazy orig-img" style="display: none;">
      <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img class="thumb" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/zingfitassets/onerebelredesign/instructor/BD8I8492_20181213103730.jpg">
      <img data-srcset="https://s3.amazonaws.com/zingfitassets/onerebelredesign/contentobject/Mark_Portrait_V2_20181213103730.gif" class="swiper-lazy orig-img" style="display: none;">
      <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img class="thumb" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/zingfitassets/onerebelredesign/instructor/BD8I8492_20181213103730.jpg">

      <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
  slidesPerView: 2,
  // Disable preloading of all images
  preloadImages: false,
  // Enable lazy loading
  lazy: {
    loadPrevNext: true
  }
});
```

Anyone who can help me with this.

Comment: What have you tried?  If you haven't even started coding yet, play with this and see where you get.  https://jsfiddle.net/GabrielS0uza/4rywvhsa/2/  Are you sure that you want to use the swiper plugin?

Comment: I have done with the lazy loading part but can't figure out how to hide and show the original image on hover. I initially set the thumbnail as regular image and original image with display none and only set data-src attribute

Comment: @natel check edit.